# For each loop returns blank

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, aspwizard

I have a for each loop in the final step of my `asp:Wizard` that is supposed to list all of the text in each textbox that is not null. The textboxes are in the second step of the `asp:Wizard` and they are placed in `asp:Panel` controls that are made visible or not visible with the use of checkboxes on the same step. Here is the event with the loop:

```
protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var requested = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                         .Where(txt => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text));

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var textBox in requested)
        {
            sb.Append(textBox.Text); //Add the text not the textbox
            sb.Append("</br>"); //Add a line break to make it look pretty
        }
        Label1.Text = sb.ToString();

    }
```

If I run the application with the loop my label will return blank, no matter what I fill out. The label is currently in the 3rd step

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep3" runat="server" AllowReturn="false" Title="Step 3" StepType="Complete">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="This text will display when I run the application without the foreach loop"></asp:Label>
</asp:WizardStep>
```

Comment: Are *TextBox*es direct child control of your page or in a panel? If yes, have you tried `var requested = somePanel.Controls.OfType.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and they are placed in asp:Panel

With `this.Controls` You are looking for the TextBoxes which exist directly on the form not inside the panel.

You should modify your query to get controls from the panel like:

```
var requested = yourPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                         .Where(txt => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text));
```

where `yourPanel` is the id of your `asp:Panel`

Answer (score 1):

You want to find a control recursively if it is nested inside other controls. Here is the helper method.

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
   if (root.ID == id) 
      return root;

   return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
      .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
      .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}
```

### Usage

```
var testbox = FindControlRecursive(Page, "NameOfTextBox");
```